# Calculating stress in a member

Tags: abaqus

I have the following question

[image]

[image]

I used abaqus software to create a sketch and added the downwards load on member BC.

However the value I get for the stress is 90185.7

Is my answer incorrect because it is not in pascals or is my answer just completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer seems correct (in magnitude), verified by a quick check on the stress of member AB shown below. You shall check/confirm the stress in member BC by hand calc though.

[image]

Comment: It doesn’t show the units in the software but the final unit should be in Pascals

Comment: What is the magnitude of force, 10695 N or 10.695 N? If it is the former, the answer is close by magnitude (91.4*1000 = 91400 Pa).

Comment: Oh okay thank you yes I may have made a slight mistake then

Comment: Also when it says to 0 decimal places does that mean leave it as 90185.7 ?

Comment: Then it shall be rounded up to 90186 Pa. Note, I am going to update the sketch to reflect the correct magnitude so people won't get confused.